# Bash terminal over http?

Tags: bash, https

I've seen a few pseudo terminals built for use in a browser e.g. https://xtermjs.org/, so I just wondered if there's a way of hosting a bash terminal in a browser that will run all the commands I enter on that machine?

I guess important things are:

1. Keyboard shortcuts and tab completion
2. Colours
3. Being able to set the port to listen on
4. If certificates are required self signed certificates must be supported
5. .bashrc should use my normal bashrc file

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 in wsl2 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Something like this: https://www.tecmint.com/access-linux-server-terminal-in-web-browser-using-wetty/

Comment: I like [gotty](https://github.com/sorenisanerd/gotty) personally

Comment: jupyter-notebook has a terminal. May be overkill because that is just a feature of a larger application, nice though... and I believe it does all of those things...

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [WeTTY](https://github.com/butlerx/wetty), which is an implementation of `xterm.js` that you mentioned.

WeTTY can be installed both natively and as a Docker container, and can connect to either localhost or a host of your choosing.

It supports [self signed certificates](https://butlerx.github.io/wetty/https) as well, so I believe all your criteria are met.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [ttyd](https://github.com/tsl0922/ttyd) over other similar programs.

Features as noted by README on GitHub:

- Built on top of Libwebsockets with libuv for speed
- Fully-featured terminal based on Xterm.js with CJK and IME support
- Graphical ZMODEM integration with lrzsz support
- SSL support based on OpenSSL
- Run any custom command with options
- Basic authentication support and many other custom options
- Cross platform: macOS, Linux, FreeBSD/OpenBSD, OpenWrt, Windows

Personally, I find it extremely easy to configure.

Command to host a bash terminal on port 1234:

```
ttyd -p 1234 bash
```

Check the link above and scroll down for more options. You can configure the password or other options.